# Encrypting filestream data

Tags: sql-server, security, sql-server-2008, filestream

SQL Server 2008 supports data at rest security through TDE (Transparent data encryption), but the encryption excludes files stored on harddrive through FILESTREAM feature.

How have you handled encryption of this data on file system stored through FILESTREAM? Encrypted File System seems to be an option, but would cause problem during DB backup, as the encryption of db and filesystem are done by two different sources using (possibly) different encryption keys! Please share your thoughts.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Can you have the folders where your FILESTREAM data reside be EFS encrypted by the account your SQL Server runs under?

Comment: @Jesse: Can EFS be restricted to folder level? I tried googling, but couldn't find a concrete explanation.

Comment: Agreed on EFS - Andrew Fryer has blogged about this a couple of times.

Comment: @pencilslate: Yes, EFS can be applied at a drive, folder and/or individual file level.

Answer (score 0):

You may also consider 3rd party tool DbDefence to encrypt filestreams.
It is free for small databases (up tp 2000 MB) but size of filestream data does not matter!

Answer (score 0):

Native TDE does not support encrypting FileStreams

However there are two third party products that offer alternatives to TDE including FileStream encryption. They both work with all versions and editions of SQL Server. One is NetLib Encryptionizer for SQL Server and the other is DBDefence. Although they both work differently. Encryptionizer sits between SQL Server and the OS, while DBDefence injects code into the running SQL process using the (now defunct) Detours SDK.  (Disclaimer: I am with [NetLib Security](https://netlibsecurity.com)).